# Почему "09/03/2021 00:00" > "07/04/2021 00:00" равно True?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Скажите, пожалуйста, почему `"09/03/2021 00:00" > "07/04/2021 00:00"` равно True?

Если сравнивать `"06/03/2021 00:00" > "07/04/2021 00:00"`, то ответом будет False.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Потому что строки (независимо от того, что в них записано) сравниваются в лексикографическом порядке (упрощенно - как слова в словаре) - сравнение просто посимвольное, причем первые символы более значимы чем последующие. Поэтому в вашем примере при большем дне дата оказывается как бы больше, и поэтому если переставить в обратном порядке (от самого значимого - года, к менее значимому - дню), то будет сравнивать "правильно" (с точки зрения человека, рассматривающего эту строку как дату).

Чтобы сравнивало именно как даты, а не как набор символов, можно преобразовать в объект даты, и уже потом сравнивать эти объекты:

```
from datetime import datetime

d1 = "09/03/2021 00:00"
d2 = "07/04/2021 00:00"

date1 = datetime.strptime(d1, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
print(repr(date1))  # Вывод: datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 9, 0, 0)

date2 = datetime.strptime(d2, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
print(repr(date2))  # Вывод: datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 7, 0, 0)

print(date1 > date2)  # Вывод: False
```

Answer (score 6):

Потому что сравниваете вы не даты, как вам хочется, а слова. А символ "9" идет в алфавите позже символа "7". Т.е. по той же причине, почему "Рязань" > "Москва".

Answer (score -1):

Сравнение дат в формате `day/month/year` - работает не правильно. Нужно использовать формат `year/month/day`.

Comment: А при чем здесь даты?? Вы же сравниваете строки, а строки сравниваются в лексикографическом порядке. Т.е. “9” > “100000”

Comment: @MaxU, не понял вашего сравнения "9" > "100000", но ведь Python может сравнивать даты, находящиеся в строках. Может я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Строка в Python представляет собой набор символов, находящихся в кавычках. При этом сравнение строк отличается от сравнения чисел и имеет свои особенности.  При сравнении символов или строк, Python конвертирует символы в их соответствующие порядковые значения, после чего сравнивает слева направо.

Comment: @S.Nick, ого! А при сравнении "2002" > "2001" Python берет по одной цифре в каждой строке и преобразует её, или он берет всё число (в нашем случае 2002, к примеру) и преобразует его в порядковое значение?

Comment: берет по одной цифре

Comment: @S.Nick, спасибо!

Comment: @S.Nick, но вот всё же думая над моим примером в ответе, почему Python "криво" сравнивает формат "day/month/year", а формат "year/month/day" нормально? Это из-за того, что иностранцы привыкли пользоваться датами второго формата? Ведь если смотреть по алгоритму сравнения строк, который Вы описали, то всё должно работать и в том и в том формате.

Comment: в текущем вопросе вы сравниваете строки, если у вас есть другие вопросы - задайте новый вопрос.

Comment: @GunTHE Формат "year/month/day" соответствует счету времени. А формат "day/month/year" не соответствует. Поэтому строковое сравнение дат в первом формате корректное, а во втором нет. Напишите несколько разных дат разных лет и месяцев и посмотрите на их вид.

Comment: @Эникейщик, спасибо